# Hide shipping address at woocommerce checkout based on a shipping table rate choice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

I have been working to hide my woocommerce checkout shipping address if a user selects a shipping table rate option that has a Label of "Local Pickup".  Most code snippets I have found trigger based on shipping_method.  I tried a shipping-method like `table_rate:10:1', to no avail. Any ideas?

Also, I am not completely clear on how to designate the specific row in the table - I inspected the code and found the value above, but am unsure if its correct.

Shipping related plug-ins: [Woocommerce Table Rate Shipping](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/table-rate-shipping/)

Trying to use the following code as a base:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'xa_remove_billing_checkout_fields' );
function xa_remove_billing_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Set the desired shipping method to hide the checkout field(s).
    $shipping_method = 'table_rate:10:1';

    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

    if ( $chosen_shipping == $shipping_method ) {
        // Add/change field name to be hide
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']); 
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

**website:** camp4coffee.com

Comment: I entered the answers to your questions above.  Thank you!

Comment: I have been to your web site and I don't see any shipping options. So I can't help, sorry.

Comment: hmm, okay, thank you.  I do have shipping options - they are all woocommerce table rate options.  That's what is making this a bit harder.